Salesforce Apex Test Case throws error despite given a value?
I get the following Error when I try to run a test case.
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Owner ID: owner cannot be blank: [OwnerId]

I've walked through in debug and can confirm that u.Id has a value.
@isTest
  static void testCreateCustomer() {
    User testUser = new User(
      Alias = 'testuser',
      Email = 'testUser@example.com',
      EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
      LastName = 'Test',
      LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
      LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
      ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User' LIMIT 1]
      .Id,
      TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
      Username = 'testUser@example.com'
    );
    insert testUser;
    User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = 'testUser@huma.us' LIMIT 1];
    
    Test.startTest();
    Account acct = new Account();
    acct.Name = 'Test Account';
    acct.OwnerId = u.Id;
    insert acct;
    Test.stopTest();
}


Do you have a trigger on Account or flow that changes the OwnerId in before insert or similar scenario? What's the full stacktrace, just the test call and that's it or something deeper?
Does it throw if you comment the line out (OwnerId not explicitly set should fallback to using test's running user as owner). Is that testUser@huma.us a normal (internal) user or some community for example?
